# Difference between module dependency and service dependency in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-module, angularjs-injector

I don't understand what's the difference between module dependency and service dependency. For example,

```
angular.module('components.users', [])
    .controller('UsersController', function(Users) {
        //...
}) 

angular.module('api.users', [])
  .factory('Users', function() {
        //...
});
```

I don't understand why `Users` service could be passed in in controller method of `components.users` as no module is required by `component.users` module. (I thought `api.users` module should be passed in in the module method as one of required modules).

In other words...

What is difference between module dependency and service dependency?

Why a service is available even when the module it is defined is not required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check if you're using an existing code base from your team that they have defined a root or base 'app' module that includes your defined 'Users' service. Below is an example of how this may be working in your project and why you're able to use the 'Users' service:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="controller">
        {{ text }}
    </div>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('services',[])
        .factory('service',function(){
            return {
                text: "this is a string value defined in a service."
            }
        })
    ;
    angular.module('controllers',[])
        /*
          Here the service "service" is being used however
          has not been specified in it's containing module.
        */
        .controller('controller',function($scope,service){
            $scope.text = service.text;
        });
    ;
    /*
      The above works because in some way all services and controllers
      have been defined. In this example by manually specifying each.
    */
    angular.module('app',['services','controllers']);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dependency between modules specifies how every module (imagine a module is a package of functionalities) needs some functionalities provided by other module(s).

Service dependency is how something (a controller, a service, etc) needs a specific service to work.

These are related. If a controller (i.e.) needs a service which is in another module, here you can evidence module dependency and service dependency. If the later mentioned service is inside the same module. The controller's module wouldn't have to depend on another module.

So imagine this:

1. ModuleA

   - Functionality1 (*Service1*)
   - Functionality2 (*Service2*)
2. ModuleB

   - Functionality3 (*Service3*)
   - Functionality4 (*Service4*)

If `Functionality1` needs `Functionality2`, it can used it without `ModuleA` needing to import `ModuleB` because they are in the same module. Now if `Functionality2` needs `Functionality4`, `ModuleA` needs to import `ModuleB` so `Functionality4` can be brought inside the "scope" (used as general sense of the word, not to be confused with [`$scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)) of `ModuleA`.

Every module in AngularJS is declared using `angular.module('name', [])` (notice the brackets). And every module (once created) can be located using `angular.module('name')` (notice the absence of brackets).

The code you provided should not work since `UsersController` (declared in `components.users` module) requires `Users` factory (declared in `api.users` module) and `components.users` module does not import `api.users`.

See it below (the code clearly fails)

```js
angular.module('components.users', [])
  .controller('UsersController', function(Users) {
    console.log(Users);
  })

angular.module('api.users', [])
  .factory('Users', function() {
    return this;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<span ng-app="components.users" ng-controller="UsersController"></span>
```

In order **to get this working** you could either declare `Users` factory inside the same `components.users` module or import `api.users` module inside `components.users`.

Options 1: declare `Users` inside the same `components.users` module.

```js
// create the module
angular.module('components.users', [])
  .controller('UsersController', function(Users) {
    console.log(Users);
  })

// locate the module
angular.module('components.users')
  .factory('Users', function() {
    return this
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<span ng-app="components.users" ng-controller="UsersController"></span>
```

Option 2: import `api.users` module inside `components.users`

```js
 
// create the module with a dependency to `api.users`
angular.module('components.users', ['api.users'])
  .controller('UsersController', function(Users) {
    console.log(Users);
  })

// create an independent module `api.users`
angular.module('api.users', [])
  .factory('Users', function() {
    return this
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<span ng-app="components.users" ng-controller="UsersController"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime when you do **`angular.module`** it becomes a separate module.

Assume you are living in an apartment, where each house is a module. Where each  house will have its own rooms(services) etc.

so when you want to access someone else house's rooms, you need to request permission from other house. in that case you are injecting the particular module and then only you will be able to access it.